# How does the torch.nn.functional.linear work?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Could you please explain to me what torch.nn.functional.linear works? and explain to me lines 23 24 and 29?
My problem is mostly about line 29 - why does fc1 need state as an input and why fc1 gives input in the first place?

```
# AI for self driving car

# Import some packages

import numpy as np
import os
import random
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as fn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.autograd as autograd
from torch.autograd import Variable

# Creating the architecture of our Neural Network

class Network (nn.Module):

    def __init__(self , input_size , nb_action):
        super(Network,self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.nb_action = nb_action
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size , 30) #Full connection 1 is the synapses for our neural network to connect the first layer ( in this case the input) to the next layer of neurons
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(30 , nb_action) #Full connection 2 is another connector to connect the hidden layer of 30 to the next layer ( in this case the output)

    #Forward method will propagate the signal from the input layer to the output layer

    def forward(self, state):
        x = fn.relu(self.fc1(state))
        q_values = self.fc2(x)
```

I've read about it in torch documentation but it's not helping.

Comment: a good start is the docs here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.linear.html

Comment: As I said I read it before but it is not helping do you have any other sources or could you explain it to me?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. `fc1` is a fully connected (dense) later and `state` is the input to the network. In this case the network consists of a fully connected layer, `relu` activation and another fully connected layer.

Comment: Note every `nn.Module` in torch has a `forward` method, and also a `__call__` method that simply calls `forward`. So `fc1.forward(state)` and `fc1(state)` are equivalent.